# Deriving a more-accurate clock from an inaccurate clock

Tags: javascript

### The Problem

I need to be able to synchronize some JavaScript events to specific timing in YouTube videos as closely as possible.  While I understand there are some [limitations to how accurate timers can be in browsers](http://ejohn.org/blog/accuracy-of-javascript-time/), I think it should be possible to do better than what I'm getting from the video player.  I used the following code on starting playback of the YouTube video.

```
startTime = new Date();
setInterval(function () {
    samples.push({player: player.getCurrentTime(), jstime: new Date() - startTime});
}, 20);
```

This code gets the current time that the video player thinks it is at with `player.getCurrentTime()`, and logs it along with regular clock time against the time that playback was started.  The following results give you an idea of the accuracy:

```
{"player":0.188,"jstime":109},
{"player":0.676,"jstime":125},
{"player":0.676,"jstime":140},
{"player":0.676,"jstime":171},
{"player":0.676,"jstime":203},
{"player":0.676,"jstime":218},
{"player":0.676,"jstime":234},
{"player":0.676,"jstime":265},
{"player":0.676,"jstime":296},
{"player":0.676,"jstime":312},
{"player":0.676,"jstime":327},
{"player":0.676,"jstime":577},
{"player":1.012,"jstime":624},
{"player":1.187,"jstime":655},
{"player":1.187,"jstime":671},
{"player":1.187,"jstime":686},
{"player":1.187,"jstime":717},
{"player":1.187,"jstime":733},
{"player":1.187,"jstime":749},
{"player":1.187,"jstime":780},
{"player":1.187,"jstime":811},
{"player":1.447,"jstime":842},
{"player":1.447,"jstime":858},
{"player":1.447,"jstime":873},
{"player":1.447,"jstime":905},
{"player":1.447,"jstime":936},
{"player":1.447,"jstime":951},
{"player":1.447,"jstime":998},
{"player":1.605,"jstime":1029},
{"player":1.605,"jstime":1061},
```

Some digging online reveals that the accuracy of the YouTube video timer comes directly from the underlying player (which will usually be HTML5 in my case), and should not be relied upon for anything more accurate than a few hundred milliseconds.

### A Possible Solution

A few observations/assumptions (and some stating the obvious):

- The time retrieved from `player.getCurrentTime()` will be approximating something constant.
- The rate at which player time passes should be nearly the same for the clock-on-the-wall.  (It may drift slightly though due to the fact that video frames are usually tied to an audio clock which always varies from machine to machine by a few Hz.)
- If I observe both clocks over time, I should be able to determine the difference in rate between them (which should be close to `0`).

Once the error rates are known and samples are taken over time, it should be possible to derive a timer that is close to the accuracy of the most accurate timer of the two (the clock provided to JavaScript).  Is this assumption correct?

### How to implement?

Given the inputs of player time and JavaScript clock-on-the-wall time, how can I derive a timer that I can call every animation frame to give me the highest accuracy possible?

How accurate could such a derived time be?

Comment: What's your case for wanting a more accurate timer? What's the application for it?

Comment: Not sure I understand this; if the JS timer is more accurate, and you have access to it, why do you need to recreate a timer?

Comment: Video has a  frame rate (24, 30, 60 fps) and count. If the timer is not accurate enough, can you use frame count instead?

Comment: @JonKoops I'm testing the feasibility of a music game (users push buttons in time to music in a video) with YouTube videos.  Most of these games need accuracy <10ms.  I know I won't go that low, but <25ms will likely be acceptable.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I need to synchronize events to the video.  Video playback time can vary slightly from device to device.  It isn't simply that a video has been playing for `x` seconds.  Using the video player's timer is the most reliable method for synchronization, but isn't accurate enough for me.  I'm hoping to derive a more accurate timer by using both the video timer and regular clock time.

Comment: @RobG Frame count or audio sample count would be perfect, but I don't think I can get that from a YouTube video, or even HTML5.  Do you know of a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured out how to accomplish this.  A bit messy for now, but you get the idea.

```
function youTubeTimer (player) {
    var startTime;
    var totalTime = 0;
    var lastPlayerTime;

    //Array of offsets between the JS timer and reported video player time
    var deltas = [];

    // Amount of time to correct
    var correction;

    player.addEventListener('onStateChange', function (e) {
        if (e.data === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
            startTime = new Date();
        } else if (e.data === YT.PlayerState.PAUSED || e.data === YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING || e.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
            totalTime = ((new Date() - startTime)/1000) + totalTime;
        }

        if (e.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
            console.log(totalTime);
        }
    });

    function getJsTime() {
        if (player.getPlayerState() === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
            return ((new Date() - startTime)/1000) + totalTime;
        } else {
            return totalTime;
        }
    }

    // Call this function frequently!
    this.getHighResPlayerTime = function getHighResPlayerTime() {
        if (!player.getCurrentTime) {
            return 0;
        }
        var playerTime = player.getCurrentTime(); // Seconds of playback, reported by the video player
        var jsTime = getJsTime();  // Seconds from the clock time when the video started

        // Has the player time been updated?  Adjust the correction offset.
        if (playerTime !== lastPlayerTime) {
            lastPlayerTime = playerTime;

            // Store up to 20 samples of offsets
            if (deltas.length >= 500) {
                deltas.shift();
            }
            deltas.push(jsTime - playerTime);

            // Calculate a new correction value
            correction = 0;
            for (var x = 0; x < deltas.length; x ++)
            {
              correction += deltas[x];
            }
            correction = correction / x;
        }
        return jsTime - correction;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done this sort of thing before (admittedly using ActionScript and targeting the AVM) but the principles still stand.

**Don't rely on the browser (or app) for timing info.**

Think about it, a little bit of buffering on the video side, or the occasional beach-ball / spinning hour glass, and suddenly your synchronisation is wrong.

What you want to do is hook into media player events, and then react to the time of the video.

The W3 HTML5 Video demo page [ http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html ] shows a whole bunch of properties and values - the ones I think you'd be wanting to take a look at are the timeUpdate event and the currentTime property.

Comment: That's exactly what I am proposing.  I need to some how factor in the current time of the video while having clock events in a higher resolution.  Unfortunately, HTML 5 videos don't have a high resolution.